# <a href> not working, after adding some jquery javascript based image sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

My Web-Design was working perfectly, however i added a trendy image slider within it from some other template, and now my  links have stopped responding. I think it is because of the Order of calling jquery scripts etc, but im not sure how should i order them to fix this issue.

Comment: where is the code bro?can you share ?

Comment: show some efforts please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions available on internet, and finally worked it out. The reason  links stopped working was because of Positioning of some jquery scripts that overlapped the whole page.

So i used z-index:100 for all  in my page, and that enabled them. Now they are working fine.

```
<style>
    body a {
        z-index: 100;
    }
</style>
```